# How to drag a rectangle using GDI+?

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+, gdi

I am trying to implement a dragging of a simple rectangle using GDI+. My code is simply working by translating the graphics object to the new position and to draw a new Rectangle.

**TransllateRectangle** is called frequently whenever **OnMouseMove** event occur.

```
void RectangleContainer::TranslateRectangle(CDC *pDC, CRect newR, CRect   oldR)
{   
   Graphics graphics(pDC->m_hDC);

   DWORD ole = m_FillColor;
   BYTE rr = ((BYTE)(ole));
   BYTE gg = ((BYTE)(((WORD)(ole)) >> 8));
   BYTE bb = ((BYTE)((ole) >> 16));

   SolidBrush linGrBrush(
      Color(125, rr, gg, bb)
   );

   Rect newRectangle = Rect(newR.left, newR.top, newR.Width(), newR.Height());

   Matrix matrix;

   matrix.Translate(newR.left - oldR.left, 0);

   graphics.SetTransform(&matrix);

   graphics.FillRectangle(&linGrBrush, newRectangle);

   graphics.~Graphics();
```

}

My problem is that I could not remove old rectangle drawn in the old position properly. How can I achieve this please?

Comment: What's the rationale behind running `graphics`' d'tor twice? Anyway, this is a common question, asked a bazillion times. The canonical answer: Get a decent book on Windows Programming. Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) is the one you need first, followed by Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC, Second Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950).

Comment: The former explains, why you need to perform all your rendering from your `WM_PAINT` handler, whereas the latter teaches you, how that translates to MFC.

Comment: I would recomment that you do not draw the rectangles like you currently do. In your OnMouseMove handler do only call the Invalidate() method of you form/control. That will raise the WM_PAINT message. In the OnPaint handler all of your form is redrawn. Just add your rectangle at its current position.